# Django Custom Form Field Property not Available in Template

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm writing a voting system that shows the number of votes for an option in the form.

I have Vote and Option models:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)

class Option(models.Model):
    prompt = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
```

I wrote a simple custom form field to hold the current number of votes:

```
class VoteField(forms.BooleanField):
    vote_count = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, option, **kwargs):
        self.vote_count = Vote.objects.filter(option=option).count()
        super(VoteField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a form to create a list of options to vote for:

```
class VoteForm(forms.BaseForm):
    base_fields = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, options, user, **kwargs):
        for options in options:
            field = VoteField(option=option)
            field.label = option.prompt
            self.base_fields["option" + str(option.pk)] = field

        super(SurveyResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I have a template to show the voting form:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{ field.label }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{ field.vote_count }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I populated the db with an option and some responses. In the shell it works as expected:

```
>>> option = Option.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> vote_field = VoteField(option=option)
>>> vote_field.vote_count
3
```

However, my template outputs nothing where I say to print vote_count:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="id_option-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        First Option
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        
    </div>    
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The "fields" that are accessed via `form.<field_name>` or `for field in form` are actually instances of `BoundField`. These `BoundField` objects are a combination of the form data and the field defined on the Form class, they are not references to the field defined on the form

To access the actual field use `field.field`

```
{{ field.field.vote_count }}
```

Comment: That's definitely non-intuitive, but it works. Thanks!